# How can you determine the classes of instances (int. vs. str. vs. bool, etc.) found in a Pandas series (a column in a DataFrame)?

Tags: python, pandas, class, types

I am trying to determine, for each column, what the datatype is in a Pandas DataFrame. Currently, if I used df.dtypes(), I get either 'object', 'float64', or 'int64'. It does not differentiate between string vs. boolean vs. time, etc. Is this possible?

Note that I have gotten error messages such as the following: "TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bool found", which makes me think that there is a native Python way to make this distinction that I am missing.

Below is an example of what I am trying to accomplish:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your problem is that you have string representations, `'TRUE'` and `'1:00:00 AM'` While these _look_ like bools and times they aren't properly stored as such, so you will need to convert them to the proper `True` Boolean and a `timedelta64[ns]` with `pd.to_timedelta`. Then the dtypes of your DataFrame will be more in line with what you want.

Comment: " string vs. boolean vs. time" those look like they are all **strings**.

Comment: Note, unless you are using `object`, your pandas data structures *don't contain python instances at all*